# How do i get the current user information from iCloud using Cloudkit , swift

Tags: swift, icloud, cloudkit

My question is how do i get the currently logged in user information from iCloud using cloudkit. i want to add more fields to this user defaults section and retrieve those data when i want it. I have tried making new schema to save user data.

Comment: What information are you looking for? CloudKit only lets you get the user's name.

Comment: @rmaddy i want to save user name , email address and contact details to the user section of the iCloud. Is there a code to fetch the user device ID and user name from the cloudkit?

Comment: Look at the docs for `CKContainer`.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to add extra fields to the User recordType in CloudKit, but it's not adviced. The User recordType is a special recordType with lots of limitations. It's better to create a new record type where you save additional user settings. Then you could set a CKReference to the actual user recordId.

For getting the active user recordID use the `CKcontainer` function `fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler`. If you want to get the first and last name (you can't get more information) then use the function `discoverUserInfoWithUserRecordID`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. i shall try to make a new record and save the user information in it. My worry is that according to Apple guidlines we are not supposed to see or discover user password, so when the user record is created a user name and password must be saved to that user record. If i do that then i will be able to see the user password. Will that cause apple to rehect my app?

Comment: You don't need a user login. When you use CloudKit, you will know for sure that his iCloud account is correct and logged in. You can query for the userID and name. If it fails you will know that the user is not logged in and you can tell the user to log in into iCloud in the settings app.

Comment: Just a note that `discoverUserInfoWithUserRecordID` is deprecated in iOS 10. The preferred methods are now the `discoverUserIdentity(with....)` methods.